# distributing 2d vector points around a sphere

Tags: three.js, geometry, distribution, packing

I'm using d3.js to create a [bubble chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269), which I'm then trying to wrap partially around a sphere in three.js.  I'd like the end result to look like a dandelion, as pictured here:
[image: dandelion]

The bubble chart on a 2d plane looks like this.  I'm trying to wrap it half-way around a sphere to create that dandelion effect.
[image: bubble chart in 2d]

I have three semi-working solutions, yet none exactly follow the curve of a sphere when viewed from the side

Example A - `zCoord = new THREE.Vector2(xCoord, yCoord).length();`
This gives a linear looking cone effect, not a curved effect.  I think I somehow need to calculate a [quadratic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves) instead of a linear line but I'm stuck trying to figure it out.
[image: side view of spheres]

Example B - `zCoord = (diameter / 2 ) * Math.cos(phi);`
This uses code from the [periodic table of elements](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) and spirals the data along the z axis.
[image: side view using phi]

Example C - Close to what I want, but it doesn't wrap around sphere enough, and everything seems to bunch up together.  I'd like to preserve the padding or space around the mini-spheres

```
zCoord = (diameter / 2 );
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord).normalize().multiplyScalar(diameter / 2);
```

[image: almost there!]

[jsfiddle link to try out the methods](http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/0bz5n5ph/1/)

Comment: You could try something like [this](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/experiments/repel/), then you could get some animation easily

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient solution, but I did get pretty close using [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).  It's almost like I'm UV wrapping, but with Vector2 points.

My solution involved mapping X,Y coords to latitude and longitude, then projecting them onto a sphere using mercator projection.

```
var latitude = data[i].position.x / R;
var longitude = (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(data[i].position.y / R))) - (Math.PI / 2);

xCoord = R * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude);
yCoord = R * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude);
zCoord = R * Math.sin(latitude);
```

[link to jsfiddle showing tweening from 2d > 3d](http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/0bz5n5ph/2/)